# Blocking function sent to_thread not executing if awaited secondly

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am learning Python asyncio and I have created a simple app to get console input and print a counter simultaneously.  I know there are packages like aioconsole, aconsole, etc. but I'm looking for an answer to the specific question in the code comments below.

UPDATE: This was solved with help from `user2357112` and from my comments to their suggestions as shown below...my solution edits are shown in-line in the code snippet below with comments "solution edit"

```
"""
Goal: simultaneously print a counter and accept keyboard input, using async concepts

"""

import asyncio

def get_console_input():
    """ Get console input forever
        This gets invoked by asyncio.to_thread since input() is blocking
        And therefore this does not get the async keyword
    """
    while True:
        s = input('> ')
        print(s)
        if s == 'x':
            return

async def counter():
    """ Print ascending counter every 1sec
    """
    i = 0
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print(i)
        i += 1

async def main():
    ## The following allows simultaneous printing of the counter and getting console input:
    # t_console = asyncio.to_thread(get_console_input)  # <-- solution edit (remove)
    coro_console = asyncio.to_thread(get_console_input)  # <-- solution edit
    t_console = asyncio.create_task(coro_console)  # <-- solution edit
    t_counter = asyncio.create_task(counter())
    await t_console  # <-- await t_console first
    await t_counter

    ## ...but the following does NOT allow simultaneous printing of the counter and getting console input:
    ## UPDATE: with changes shown on the lines marked with "solution edit", now this works as expected
    #  t_console = asyncio.to_thread(get_console_input)
    #  t_counter = asyncio.create_task(counter())
    #  await t_counter  # <-- await t_counter first
    #  await t_console

    ## If I "await t_console" before "await t_counter", then it works (the counter is printed and console input is allowed simultaneously)
    ## But if I "await t_counter" before "await t_console", then it does not work (the counter is printed but console input is never allowed/executed)
    ## ...seems like "await t_counter" should suspend the counter() coroutine at the asyncio.sleep(1) line inside counter() to then let the "await t_console" line execute...but it's not doing that...why?
    ## UPDATE: with changes shown on the lines marked with "solution edit", all works as expected

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Answer (score 0):

You say

> ...seems like "await t_counter" should suspend the counter() coroutine at the asyncio.sleep(1) line inside counter() to then let the "await t_console" line execute...but it's not doing that...why?

That's not how `await` works. If its argument suspends, `await` doesn't finish and move on to the next line. The `await` will suspend too - it *waits* for its argument to finish.

Your `await`s don't happen in parallel, no matter which one you put first. Here's what's going on.

---

`asyncio.to_thread` is a coroutine function, much like your `counter`. Both `asyncio.to_thread(get_console_input)` and `counter()` produce coroutine objects, which are not automatically scheduled. `asyncio.to_thread` will run `get_console_input` in another thread, but it can't do that until the `to_thread` coroutine itself runs.

With `t_counter = asyncio.create_task(counter())`, you create a task for your `counter()` coroutine. This tells the event loop to schedule this task and run that coroutine independently of your `main` coroutine (as independent as coroutines in the same event loop can be, anyway).

Your `asyncio.to_thread(get_console_input)` coroutine has no task. It doesn't run until you `await t_console`. When `await t_console` is after `await t_counter`, `await t_console` never runs, because `await t_counter` never finishes. `t_console` never gets a chance to start the worker thread.

If you create a task for the `to_thread` coroutine:

```
t_console = asyncio.create_task(asyncio.to_thread(get_console_input))
```

then both tasks will run, regardless of which you `await` first.

Alternatively, you can run both coroutines with `asyncio.gather`:

```
t_console = asyncio.to_thread(get_console_input)
t_counter = counter()
await asyncio.gather(t_console, t_counter)
```

This schedules both coroutines and waits for both to finish, regardless of what order you pass the arguments to `gather`.

Comment: True, good point that `asyncio.to_thread()` returns a *coroutine* object (not a *task* object), so my variable name `t_console` should be changed to `coro_console` (just for naming clarity) -- I've updated my code snippet above (tagged with "solution edit").  But that made me think and it shed light on how to fix this...I found that if I create a console *task* from that console *coroutine*, then it works: `coro_console = asyncio.to_thread(get_console_input)` followed by `t_console = asyncio.create_task(coro_console)` (also added to the code snippet above, tagged with "solution edit").

Comment: Now, as I would expect, it works regardless of the order in which I await t_console or t_counter.  It looks like your edits to your answer align with my discoveries and we've arrived at the same conclusion.  So now, the code is awaiting the console *task* and not awaiting the console *coroutine*.  So awaiting a task is somehow different than awaiting a coroutine(?) -- this might be related to your comment that coroutine objects are "produced but not automatically scheduled".  I up-voted your answer because it made me think and led me to a solution which aligned with yours.  Thank you!